# Close current tab firefox and opera using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, opera

How to close current tab in java script.

I tried this :

```
 var win = window.open("","_self");
 win.close();
```

and

```
 window.close();
```

Both work in chrome but this code is not working in firefox version - 20.0 and 
opera 12.16.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

those browsers allow scripts to close only windows that created by scripts